# Mongodb connection string Invalid keyword data source

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using C# official MongoDB nugget library.

I hosted the web service on `Windows Azure`, and the MongoDB database at `Mongolab`.

I connected to a server with the code below:

```
connection = mongodb://user:pass@ds049999.mongolab.com:45077"
_server = MongoServer.Create(connection);
```

Previously it is working fine and it work fine at local testing server, but at my latest publish I get error below:

```
ExceptionMessage":"Invalid keyword 'data source'."," ....... at MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@ds049999.mongolab.com:45077");
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("MyDataBaseName");
```

If your username or password contains special characters, you might want to encode them.

Please also note that your database username and password may well be different to your MongoLab login!